# Report total summary in XtraReports Devexpress Programmatic?

Tags: c#, devexpress, summary, xtrareport

Am trying to populate data to reports programmatically. That's working fine, Now am trying to show **Total summary** for **amount column** in XtraReport using this code on BeforePrint & AfterPrint events but i din't get summary total, simply it shows **?** or **None**

```
TXE_Total.Summary = new XRSummary(SummaryRunning.Report, SummaryFunc.Sum, "{0:n2}");
```

Am tried SummaryRunning to **Report, Page, Group** but didn't get Summary total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you forgot to add bindings for your `XRLabel`:

```cs
TXE_Total.DataBindings.Add(new XRBinding("Text", null, "AmountField"));
TXE_Total.Summary = new XRSummary(SummaryRunning.Report, SummaryFunc.Sum, "{0:n2}");
```